# "Minified React error #418 and #423 in Next.js v12.3.1 with React v18.2.0"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

After major updates, I started encountering the following errors in my application:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error- 
decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment 
for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error- 
decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment 
for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

These errors don't specify the exact component or code causing the issue, and I'm having trouble pinpointing the source of the problem in my application.

Environment:

Next.js version: 12.3.1
React version: 18.2.0

My question is :

What steps can I take to identify/fix the specific component or code causing these minified React errors?

please refer to the image below:
[image]

Comment: Hydration errors are caused by invalid markup like `div` tags inside a `p` tag or by client components that have different values on the server and on the client.

Comment: @FabioNettis I have checked and there is no such cases, I'm trying to track the error and it seems it might be coming from a context provider, which does not return any jsx or html tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a couple of days I was able to finally find 2 solutions to these 2 errors:

1. downgrade current react version from v18 to v17.0.2
2. I had several components/functions that are being used by context provider so I dynamically imported all those components, providers and even a function that triggers an API call, so first you import dynamic from next.js like the following :
   a. import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
   b. const ExampleComponent = dynamic(() => import("./path/toComponent"));

these 2 methods solved both errors for me, if you decide to choose second option you do not need to downgrade your react version. I hope someone finds these helpful

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was due to a DIV inside an A tag, by removing the  inside the  component leaving only the div and using the legacyBehavior attribute the error disappeared!